# Why the limit of $\frac{\log n}{n} \int_2^n \frac{1}{\log x} d x $ is $1$?

Tags: calculus

$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log n}{n} \int_2^n \frac{1}{\log x}
   d x = 1
$$
I tried to find the integral but the integral by itself does not converge.
When applying the Mean Value Theorem I can find that one side of my inequality is equal to 1 but I cannot prove the equality.

Comment: Not an answer but have you tried taking the derivative of x/ln(x) ?

Comment: L'Hospital is your friend.

Comment: What happened when you tried to find the integral?  Were you able to find an antiderivative for finite $n$?

Comment: @mathematician This is the logarithmic integral, which is well-known to not be elementary. See, e.g., Hardy, *The Integration of Functions of a Single Variable*.

Comment: Split the integral at $y := \dfrac{n}{(\log n)^2}$. The first part is smaller than $y\cdot\dfrac{1}{\log 2}$, so upon multiplication with $\frac{\log n}{n}$ we get something that vanishes (namely $\dfrac{1}{(log 2)\log n}$). Squeeze the second part between $\dfrac{n-y}{\log n}$ and $\dfrac{n-y}{\log y}$. Since $\dfrac{\log y}{\log n} = 1 - 2\dfrac{\log \log n}{\log n} \to 1$, the result follows.

Answer (score 7):

By L'Hospital,

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log n}{n} \int_2^n \frac{1}{\log x}
   d x = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1/\log(n)}{\frac{d}{d n} \frac{n}{\log n}} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1/\log(n)}{1/\log(n) - 1/\log(n)^2} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{1- 1/\log(n)} = 1
$$

Comment: How do you obtain the first equality? Never mind, Thanks!

Comment: Say $f(x) = 1/ \log(x)$ and its antiderivative is $F(x)$. So the definite integral is $F(n) - F(2)$ which diverges with $n$. So does $n/\log n$. Using L'Hospital, the numerator is  $\frac{d}{d n} (F(n) - F(2)) = f(n) = 1/ \log(n)$.

Answer (score 7):

Integration by parts gives
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_2^n\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\log(x)}\\
&=\left.\frac{x}{\log(x)}\right]_2^n+\int_2^n\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\log(x)^2}\\
&=\frac{n}{\log(n)}-\frac{2}{\log(2)}+O\!\left(\frac{n}{\log(n)^2}\right)\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
The big-O estimate is valid since for $n\ge e^3$,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_2^n\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\log(x)^2}
&=\int_2^{e^3}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\log(x)^2}+\int_{e^3}^n\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\log(x)^2}\\
&\le\int_2^{e^3}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\log(x)^2}
+3\int_{e^3}^n\left(\frac1{\log(x)^2}-\frac2{\log(x)^3}\right)\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_2^{e^3}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\log(x)^2}
+3\left[\frac{x}{\log(x)^2}\right]_{e^3}^n\\
&=\int_2^{e^3}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\log(x)^2}
-\frac{e^3}3+3\frac{n}{\log(n)^2}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Multiply $(1)$ by $\frac{\log(n)}{n}$ and take the limit as $n\to\infty$.